# Is there any alternate for tfagents in pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

We are using `tfagents` in `tensorflow` for reinforcement learning, because of limitations with static computation graphs we are planning to migrate our code to pytorch.

`tfagents` is great and have very good documentation and reduce a lot of time doing the same task again

We are wondering if the `pytorch` community have a similar kind of stuff?

Comment: The question is flag as a **Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more** but I think it's unfair. I think such a question is ok to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rllib](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/rllib.html) is an alternative which supports PyTorch.